# displaying progress bar for labjs, labjs callbacks

Tags: javascript, labjs, dynamic-script-loading

How can I keep track of what scripts have been loaded so far so I can display a progress bar when using labjs (http://labjs.com/)? `wait()` doesn't work because then it won't parallel load the next resource. Basically i'm looking for some kind of non-blocking callback function i can tie into. Does this exists in labjs?

Answer (score 0):

1. `wait()` does not affect the parallel loading of LABjs... it will always parallel load as much as possible (allowed by the browser). `wait()` only affects the execution of scripts. If it's inserted between two `script()` calls, it ensures that the second script will "wait" for the first script to finish executing before it executes.
2. No, there is no exposed API for the load-finishing on scripts, because browsers do not expose a consistent API for when a script finishes loading (only when it executes: "onload", as confusing as that name is).

Now, you **can** do a progress meter using `wait()` calls in between each script, but it will tell you something slightly different than what you asked: what percentage of the scripts have **executed**, not what percentage of the scripts have **downloaded**. Depending on your needs, that might be quite acceptable.

Comment: @LordZardeck depends on what you mean by "affects performance". `wait()` does not affect the performance of parallel downloads. however, if you use a `wait()` to delay the execution of a critical piece of code, and something before the `wait()` is slow to load or run, then the critical code will be delayed (obviously), and this will definitely affect "perceived" performance. Rule of thumb: only make a piece of code wait to execute if it really needs to wait. if it can run independently, either leave off the `wait()` that holds it up, or use a separate $LAB chain.